# Free X server for windows

Tags: windows, linux, x-server

Is there a (preferably free) X server software package that I can use to connect to Linux box from Windows?  I've tried exceed from hummingbird, but it's expensive, are there free alternatives with the same quality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i'd suggest taking look at [xming](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/) or [mobaxterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/)

Comment: can xming be integrated with xshell? or does it need to be putty?

Comment: well, for most part, places where i used xming had it already set up, so i never really got to poke at it. i don't recall what they used with it. http://www.doxer.org/learn-linux/use-xming-xshell-to-display-linux-gui-to-windows-desktop-x11-forwarding/ this indicates its possible.

Answer (score 1):

There's [Cygwin/X](http://x.cygwin.com/).   Can be overkill just for X (although a highly recommend installing cygwin anyway), or [xming](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/) which is more self contained.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from xming, there is also a free application called [vcxsrv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/files/) which is similar to xming but freely available. The use of this program is similar to xming.